# VBA Actuarial Triangle If-Then-Else code

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, reference, cell

I'm new to this site, and I'm hoping someone can help me with an Excel VBA question. I'm trying to return the last cell that has data in each row of an actuarial triangle. I have about 400 triangles with about 15 rows of data each I need to return the last cell that has data in each row for.

But since the column of the cell was data for each successive row is two columns to the left of the row above, I can't do a simple ="$"column""row" function. I think a IF THEN ELSE statement loop VBA would be my best bet. But since I've never written a VBA code before, I'm not sure how to start. Can anyone give guidance on how to start? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you don't really need vba for this:

=lookup(1E+100,A1:G1)
for example will return the last number in A1:G1. adjust the column references and copy as needed :-)